# Unknown error -1=ffffffffffffffff Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1 in Jenkins

Tags: ios, xcode, jenkins

```
Code Signing /Users/administrator/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Project-fsoqxyfpecqjwcerfwewjovbrmnf/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Project/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/Project.app/Frameworks/Bolts.framework with Identity iPhone Distribution: PRASAD SOFT, INC. (**********)
/usr/bin/codesign --force --sign DFFCCDF13EC4BD54B0E8CA11E115D0E77F1C284D  --preserve-metadata=identifier,entitlements '/Users/administrator/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Project-fsoqxyfpecqjwcerfwewjovbrmnf/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Project/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/Project.app/Frameworks/Bolts.framework'
/Users/administrator/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Project-fsoqxyfpecqjwcerfwewjovbrmnf/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Project/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/Project.app/Frameworks/Bolts.framework: **unknown error -1=ffffffffffffffff
Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1**

** ARCHIVE FAILED **

The following build commands failed:


PhaseScriptExecution [CP]\ Embed\ Pods\ Frameworks /Users/administrator/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Project-fsoqxyfpecqjwcerfwewjovbrmnf/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Project/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Project.build/Release-QA-iphoneos/Shotzr.build/Script-2552EF011E9D1FCA909096CD.sh
(1 failure)

Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: That's not a Jenkins problem, I would say. Make sure that the command that you're running works.

Comment: Yes xcodeBuild command working fine with my Mac terminal (Command line).

Comment: During build execution in Mac terminal it asked user id and password once, I provided it then build succeeded.   In jenkins  I am facing this issue, I provided same commands in job config of jenkins through 'execute shell' option in 'Build step'. Shell script in not passing is problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am going to chip in as well: the problem was with keychain use through SSH. I had to execute these in my session to fix it:

```
security unlock-keychain -p MY_PASS ~/Library/Keychains/login.keychain
security set-key-partition-list -S apple-tool:,apple:,codesign: -s -k MY_PASS ~/Library/Keychains/login.keychain
security set-keychain-settings ~/Library/Keychains/login.keychain
```

I've also removed my current certificates system/account certificates by removing my account from XCode (I use fastlane to do building) but I suspect that this shouldn't have impacted it.

Answer (score 5):

That's a code signing error, the xcodebuild command can't access your keychain since it's running through Jenkins' slave with SSH.

Run this line on your shell script before you run the xcodebuild in order to allow access:

```
security set-key-partition-list -S apple-tool:,apple: -s -k <ROOT-PASSWORD> /Users/<YOUR USER NAME>/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: I just wanted to chime in -- since this isn't marked as the answer -- that adding this step before my job's xcodebuild command fixed my issue. I recently switched Jenkins from manually running the JAR on my slave to SSHing into the slave from master and this error popped up as a result. Thanks, @Asaf!